# Best application for process flow with expandable attributes

Tags: flowchart

I am looking for the best software application to do the following

I have a set of use cases that are in relationship to each other. I want to show an overview of this relationship. If the user desires the attributes for each use case (such as business rules, data elements, etc) should be expandable. This is potentially a large map which is the reason why the attributes should be expandable / collapsable.

Finally all this needs to be printable.

Any idea of the ideal application to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you no longer need the answer to this question, but google is still directing people here, so I will provide an answer.

I believe that the free version of [xmind](https://www.xmind.net/) will do what you want, using a combination of the following features:

- floating topics for the major blocks (position using shift+drag, or
  menu->modify->align floating topic to avoid auto-snapping)
- relationship lines
- expandable/collapsible trees of subtopics
- ability to "drill down" into a block and display a complete sub-diagram

The tool is primarily for mind-mapping and does that best, but I believe the formatting is sufficiently flexible for most flow-charts

I have tried other tools - freemind, opengeode, treeform, gliffy and lucidchart - but I do not believe any of them is sufficiently flexible to accommodate your need.

Comment: Google brought me here and this is useful information

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head Microsoft Visio will probably do all this for you

Comment: Unfortunately Visio does not allow for the expandable / collapsable view of the attributes...

At least as far as the people I asked and I know